How to query a record by it's highest value when grouping by hour
we have a database table where we store a new record every 30 minutes.
The data looks like this:

I wrote the following query:
SELECT *
FROM datastore_usage
WHERE datastore_id = 1
GROUP BY HOUR(created_at)
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 10;

This query results in the following:

Instead of the first value of the given hour, I would like to get the record with the highest bytes_in_use of this hour.
I have tried to add the MAX(bytes_in_use) to the query. But then the value is not related to the ID and created at timestamp.
So how can I query the highest record grouped by hour?
Than you in advance.

I wrote the following query It is incorrect. Incomplete grouping. Enable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY. how can I query the highest record grouped by hour? What is MySQL version precisely?

The data looks like this See Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question, #5 and #3.

I finally fixed the issue by using the following query:

SELECT MAX(bytes_in_use), created_at 
FROM datastore_usage 
WHERE datastore_id = 1 
GROUP BY DATE(created_at), HOUR(created_at) 
ORDER BY created_at DESC 
LIMIT 10

This query returns the highest value of each hour. It still returns the first timestamp of the hour. But we will round this timestamp anyway.

As pointed out by Akina in the comments above, your query is only working because you do not have ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY enabled. You should read MySQL Handling of GROUP BY. This db<>fiddle shows the error you should be receiving and some alternative ways of writing your query.

Try if it produces desired result and let me know. If yes i can explain.
  WITH CTE AS (
SELECT 
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY HOUR(created_at) ORDER BY bytes_in_use DESC) AS row_num
FROM 
    datastore_usage
WHERE 
    datastore_id = 1
)
SELECT 
*
FROM 
CTE
WHERE 
row_num = 1
ORDER BY 
created_at DESC
LIMIT 10;


Answer needs formatting
